# Completing badge creates graphical glitch in "achievements"

Tags: bug, design

Here's the picture:

[image]

As you can see, the badge I was tracking, "Electorate", bugged when it was completed (and before I had chosen a new badge to track). It shows 64/25 which is the [percentage requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) of Electorate.

I think the Electorate progress bar is meant to switch to show the percentage when 600 question votes are reached and vice versa (e.g. display your progress in the not yet completed area of the badge), however the bug seems to be that it is switching to the alternate even when *both* are reached.

Comment: 64/25 is the question vote percentage as a total of all votes. 25% of votes have to be on questions. The rest I dunno.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'll edit that in as it seems helpful